# Footnotes without markers only in the text, and with markers before the note words

Tags: footnotes

Now what is needed is to add a footnote that is not attached to any place in the document, yet it is counted in the counter and appears. What's more, I want the footnote's number to appear before the words of the note. (So it's like a 'ghost' footnote that refers to nowhere.)

Comment: This seems quite difficult to me. So at first one question: Why? It is not a good style to give a number without its reference. Imagine reading a footnote labelled "xy" and not being able to find its reference on the pages around. It should be clear that there is no reference and therefore there should be no number (there are several solutions for this case on this site). If you really want to get your described result, please provide a minimal working example which shows your documentclass and your footnote related packages.

Comment: I'm typesetting a historical document and this is how it appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would clearly advice against such an approach. If the footnote is interesting to the reader (and I hope it is), he will start searching for its origin in the text and will not find it. No reference, no number!

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct} % just a recommendation, not needed.
\setlength{\textheight}{3cm} % for demo

\begin{document}
Test 1\footnote{Footnote with mark.}. Test 2\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Footnote without mark.}. Test 3\footnote{Footnote with mark again.}.    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never took into consideration that such an easy trick would work -- how did you find out? +1!

Comment: Needed some (well, pretty much) googling... Found it on a lilypond page. When I saw it, it was quite logical :-)

Comment: What is the use of the package 'fnpct', sir?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon It reduces the distance between period and footnotemark and it controls which symbol is set first. See http://ctan.org/pkg/fnpct

Comment: This also works with endnotes: ``\stepcounter{endnote}\endnotetext{Endnote without mark.}``. I needed this because my first note refers to a note mark on my title page, which is compiled separately from the main document.

Comment: I've been looking all over for this.  While you didn't recommend using this approach, I feel that my use-case is justified.  I'm making a poster where I borrowed a LateX template.  I wish to create a footnote to thank the creator of the template, without referencing to it explicitly from the main content of the poster.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[pagesize, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
This is the quick and dirty »solution«:

Hello World\footnote{No anchor}\llap{\color{white}\textsuperscript{1}}\llap{.} Here we
go. Next\footnote{With anchor}

If you use KOMA-script, what about this missing anchor:%
\addtokomafont{footnotereference}{\color{white}}?\footnote{No
  anchor}\llap{.} \addtokomafont{footnotereference}{\color{black}} And now
we've got the references back.\footnote{Hopefully}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This results in a grey outlined "1" (sumatra), too little space in front of "Here", too big space in front of "And", and incompatibility with the package `fnpct` (last thing is off topic, but as this package is so cool...)